# Adding images to Android Studio 1.3.1 projects

Tags: java, android, image

I'm making an app and I have moved to Android Studio 1.3.1 since it has improved alot lately. I have a row of `ImageButtons` in my `activity_main.xml`. Then I have right clicked on `drawable` folder choosing `NewImageAsset`. I have tried Asset Type `Launcher Icons`, `Action Bars and Tab Icons` and `Notification Icons` and chosen an image. Android Studio render hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi versions of the image.

But still the `android:src="@drawable/backwardImage` gives me `Cannot resolve android:src="@drawable/backwardImage"`.

How do you do this in android Studio 1.3.1? I'm pretty sure there is a really simple answer.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/backwardImage"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton01"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/backwardImage"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton02"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/backwardImage"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton03"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Regards,

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried your way.

Using explorer, go to source, paste my image inside drawable folder. Go to Android studio and you will see the image (same as drawable-xhdpi, etc.)

Another way is just drag your image from explorer to your drawable in Android studio.

Note: your image should be png or jpg. Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after 2 days of looking I finally found this proj_name/app/src/main/res/drawable-folder. I changed the names to lower case only and it actually works!
Tomas